# Why is monit not restarting the server

Tags: monitoring, monit

I have configured monit on a Ubuntu machine with the following configuration:

```
check process apache with pidfile /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/apache2 start" with timeout 60 seconds
  stop program  = "/etc/init.d/apache2 stop"
  if cpu > 80% for 5 cycles then restart
  if children > 250 then restart
```

but is not working. The server has become offline on occasions and nothing seemed to have happened.

Any ideas of why it is not restarting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "server has become offline on occasions". As it can mean that the node where Apache was running was shutdown and it can also mean that `http://localhost:80/` was not accessible.

If later was the case then changing the configuration to

```
check process apache with pidfile /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/apache2 start" with timeout 60 seconds
  stop program  = "/etc/init.d/apache2 stop"
  if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 80 then restart
  if cpu > 80% for 5 cycles then restart
  if children > 250 then restart
```

might work. As your configuration will not restart Apache if its process was running but because of any issue was not accessible at `http://localhost:80/`